# Generating ethereum address from ECDSA Public Key

Tags: ethereum, web3js

I am using node-webcrypto-p11 and generating keys via following code

```
keys = crypto.subtle.generateKey({name: "ECDSA", namedCurve: "K-256"}, false, ["sign", "verify"]);
```

what is the eth address.

```
('0x' + keccak('keccak256').update(key).digest().slice(-20).toString('hex');)
```

I am finding eth address like this is this correct?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems right to me. You can test your solution with this little script

```js
const wallet = require('ethereumjs-wallet');

var account = wallet.fromPrivateKey(Buffer.from('348ce564d427a3311b6536bbcff9390d69395b06ed6c486954e971d960fe8709', 'hex'));
console.log(account.getChecksumAddressString());
```

or with web3:

```js
var account = web3.eth.accounts.privateKeyToAccount('0x348ce564d427a3311b6536bbcff9390d69395b06ed6c486954e971d960fe8709');
console.log(account.address);
```